# Problem with listing numbering in caption

Tags: captions, listings, chapters

When I want to put a simple caption to my listing, tex puts the number of the subheading to the listing and not the actual listing number.

```
\begin{lstlisting}[language=Python, caption=Listing 1: caption, captionpos=b]
 some code 
\end{lstlisting}
```

[image]

As you see here, it also adds the chapter number instead of only listing 1.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please reveal which document class you employ.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`listings` offers the `numberbychapter` option which is initially set to true. Using `\lstset{numberbychapter=false}` you can make sure, listings are numbered continuously throughout the document without the chapter number prefix:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{numberbychapter=false}
\begin{document}
\chapter{chapter}

\begin{lstlisting}[language=Python, caption=caption, captionpos=b]
 some code 
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```